# Is it possible to get the location of the jlink image when an application is run using the launcher?

Tags: java, jlink

For example, here's the outputted jlink image:

```
├── bin
│   ├── java
│   ├── keytool
│   └── launcher
├── conf
│   ├── net.properties
│   ├── sdp
│   └── security
├── include
│   ├── classfile_constants.h
│   ├── jni.h
│   ├── jvmticmlr.h
│   ├── jvmti.h
│   └── linux
├── legal
│   └── java.base
├── lib
│   ├── classlist
│   ├── jexec
│   ├── jrt-fs.jar
│   ├── jspawnhelper
│   ├── jvm.cfg
│   ├── libjava.so
│   ├── libjimage.so
│   ├── libjli.so
│   ├── libjsig.so
│   ├── libnet.so
│   ├── libnio.so
│   ├── libverify.so
│   ├── libzip.so
│   ├── modules
│   ├── security
│   ├── server
│   └── tzdb.dat
├── man
│   └── man1
└── release
```

In the `bin` dir, I have the `launcher` file which will execute my modular Java application.

My plan is to add more directories such as `settings`, `work` etc to the outputted jlink image directory. The users will simply get this image as a zip file, and use the `launcher` file after unzipping to run my application.

The problem is that I have no idea how to get access to my custom added directories (such as `settings`, `work`, etc) since the user could unzip this image anywhere. If I could somehow get the location of this image, everything would work great. Perhaps there is a way to figure out the location of java executable (since it would just be the java executable present in the `bin` directory) running my program? I'm not sure.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can probably get the location of your JAR/class file. Would that be enough, given that the folder structure is known?

Comment: I believe so. But I don't believe it's possible to get that information when using jlink?

Comment: But... Have you actually tried? What is the output when running as a normal module versus in a jlink environment? Because the launcher is not a binary a la eclipse rcp; it's just a script that calls java.

Comment: Yes, of course. It gives me the jrt path when getting the path of a class.

Comment: For reference, here's one of the things I've tried: `getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();`

Comment: So you get either the path to your jar or the path to the jrt. This is enough for you to know the overall folder that your program has been installed in, as they are in known locations inside the tree.

Comment: @JavierMartín Perhaps I'm misunderstanding what you're saying, but this is what I get for that line of code in a modular app: `jrt:/org.example.core`. So it's just printing out the package name, and not the file system location. I don't believe I can leverage that to get a file system location.

Comment: ah, okay, so you want the root of the jrt filesystem. Maybe you can read the value of the system property "java.home" then.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who reach this question without an answer, use `System.getProperty("java.home")`